# Should services ask for credentials at each request?

Tags: web-services, security, language-agnostic, authentication, service

I wonder what is the optimal authentication method for services and webservices:

1. user/password is sent on each request
2. user/password is sent once to obtain an authentication code that will be sent on each request

Is there any alternative? Which is better? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the protocol.

If the service requests are in the clear (http), then you might want to consider a secure (https) logon transaction, which gains you a limited-time token to authorise future requests (a session cookie, in effect). Then at least eavesdroppers don't get credentials that work forever, just for a limited period.

Likewise even if the logon transaction isn't secure, at least if it only happens once it's slightly harder to eavesdrop. It's also slightly harder to use.

If you don't care about security, I wouldn't even use a username/password, just an API key. Amounts to the same thing, but if the user doesn't choose it then at least it won't be similar to any of their other passwords, so it doesn't affect anything else when it's stolen.

If you care about security sufficiently that everything is done over https, then it doesn't really make a lot of difference what identification mechanism you use, AFAIK. So do something simple.

Finally, you might care about the security of the authentication, but not about the secrecy of the requests themselves. So, you don't mind eavesdroppers seeing the data in flight, you just don't want them to be able to issue requests of their own (or spoof responses). In that case, you could sign the requests (and responses) using a public/private keypair or a shared secret with HMAC. That might (or might not) be easier to set up and lower bandwidth than SSL. Beware replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

By optimal are you thinking about performance ? I would suggest to send credentials and authenticate on each request unless you really find this to be a bottleneck. SSL is not enough at all, it only provides encryption and authentication of the web service. But think about client authentication (a client cert can help here) and authorisation, may be not all users of the web service is not allowed to call all methods and all methods calls needs to be logged for auditing. In this case the user identity needs to presented for each call.

I develop and maintain a SOA based core system web service developed in WCF that authenticates and authorises against .Net based clients using windows identity and uses 2-way certs authentication against Java clients and I have no performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Jessop clarified things for me:

1. if the credentials are memorized I should provide a transient authentication cookie after they are received,
2. but if the credentials are digitally stored then I should only use an API key, because anyone who can access the credential storage wouldn't need to access the cookie